# Dimension of pre image of hyperplane

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I try to solve an exercise in Gathmann's notes in AG. We have nonconstant
$f:\mathbb{P}^m\rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$ morphism, $H\subset\mathbb{P}^n$ an hyperplane.
The claim is that $f^{-1}(H)$ is at least of dimension $m-1$.

I though to write $f^{-1}(H)= \cup_{i=1}^k A_i$, where $A_i$ are the irreducible components, and then show that there exist $A_i$ such that $dimA_i\ge m-1$. But I don't know how to do it.

Comment: What if $f$ is a constant outside that hyperplane? Then the preimage of $H$ is empty. Can that happen? What does "morphism" mean in this context?

Comment: @Compacto I forgot to mention, $f$ is not constant.

Answer (score 1):

well, $f:\mathbb{P}^m \rightarrow \mathbb{P}^n$
corresponds to a morphism of graded rings
$\phi_f: K[X_0, ..., X_n] \to K[Y_0, ..., Y_m], 
X_i \mapsto F_i(Y)$ where $F_i$ are homogeneous of same degree.
If $H= V_+(L), L$ homogeneous linear polynomial,
then $(f^{-1}(H))_{red} = V_+(\phi_f(L))$. Futhermore $\dim (f^{-1}(H))_{red}= \dim (f^{-1}(H))$, so taking reduced scheme not destroys the argument. That's a hyperplane
in $\mathbb{P}^m$ iff $\phi_f(L) \neq 0$, otherwise
that's the whole $\mathbb{P}^m$.

Answer (score 1):

Possible idea for proof:

The hyperplane $H$ is given by the equation $\omega(y_0,\dots, y_n) = 0$, where $\omega$ is a linear polynomial in homogeneous coordinates. Then, $f^{-1}(H)$ is given by $\omega(f(x_0,\dots, x_m)) = 0$. Can this be used to compute the dimension? I imagine that, since it's a variety given by only one equation, it's a hypersurface, and its irreducible components are zeros of irreducible factors of $\omega \circ f$.

Comment: yes, essentially we are using the same argument, namely that the preimage of $H$ is given by vanishing set of a single homogeneous polynomial: $\omega(f(x_0,\dots, x_m))$. And it's known that this vanishing set has codimension at most $1$ in $\mathbb{P}^m$. Namely it has codimension $1$ iff $\omega(f(x_0,\dots, x_m))$ is zero (for general schemes if it's nilpotent)

Comment: I understand, but I've never studied schemes, graded rings, etc, so I can't fully understand how you expressed it.